# MYSQL query - getting totals by month and show zero total

Tags: mysql, select

I have like this table

```
 MySQL> select * from order;
    +-----+-------------+---------------+
    | id  | order_total |  payment_date |
    +-----+-------------+---------------+
    |   1 |          35 |    2015-05-17 |
    |   2 |          35 |    2015-03-17 |
    |   3 |          65 |    2015-02-04 |
    |   4 |          39 |    2015-01-01 |
    |   5 |          19 |    2015-01-21 |
    |   6 |          27 |    2015-10-21 |
    |   7 |          74 |    2015-02-15 |
    |   8 |          81 |    2015-09-13 |
    |   9 |          86 |    2015-03-01 |
    |  10 |          42 |    2015-07-08 |
    |  11 |          73 |    2015-05-19 |
    |  12 |          78 |    2015-07-20 |
    |  13 |          92 |    2015-02-04 |
    ......
    |1913 |          71 |    2015-11-04 |
    +-----+-------------+---------------+
```

I need the result to show me each month payment for year 2015 
I try to use

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(payment_date), 
       SUM(order_total) 
FROM order 
GROUP BY YEAR(payment_date), 
         MONTH(payment_date)
```

but its not giving the zero months 
I read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841549/mysql-select-the-count-of-records-for-every-month) also but he have tow table
I need the result to show me each month payment with total like this

```
+-----+-------+
| MM  | Total | 
+-----+-------+
|  01 |  5735 |
|  02 |  2535 | 
|  03 |  1065 | 
|  04 |     0 | 
|  05 |   919 | 
|  06 |     0 | 
|  07 |  2874 | 
|  08 |     0 | 
|  09 |  6086 | 
|  10 |  2042 | 
|  11 |  1973 | 
|  12 |     0 | 
+-----+-------+
```

Comment: You need to have a dates or months table and then you can use that with an `outer join`...

Answer (score 1):

There needs to be a row source for the months, the twelve rows you need returned. There's several possible ways to do that. One approach is to use an inline view to return the twelve rows, without creating a table.

For example:

```
 SELECT i.mm                         AS `mm`
      , IFNULL(SUM(o.order_total),0) AS `total`
   FROM ( SELECT '01' AS mm
          UNION ALL SELECT '02'
          UNION ALL SELECT '03'
          UNION ALL SELECT '04'
          UNION ALL SELECT '05'
          UNION ALL SELECT '06'
          UNION ALL SELECT '07'
          UNION ALL SELECT '08'
          UNION ALL SELECT '09'
          UNION ALL SELECT '10'
          UNION ALL SELECT '11'
          UNION ALL SELECT '12'
        ) i
   LEFT
   JOIN `order` o
     ON o.payment_date >= '2015-01-01' + INTERVAL ( i.mm - 1 ) MONTH 
    AND o.payment_date  < '2015-01-01' + INTERVAL ( i.mm + 0 ) MONTH
  GROUP BY i.mm
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a month table with all the months. Check this **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132024/how-to-populate-a-table-with-a-range-of-dates)**

**allMonths**

```
  id, year, month
```

Then create a left join

```
 SELECT a.year, a.month,  COALESCE(SUM(o.order_total ),0) as total
 FROM allMonths a
 LEFT JOIN orders o
        ON a.year = YEAR(payment_date)
       AND a.month = MONTH(payment_date)
 GROUP BY a.year, 
          a.month
```

**EDIT:**

Also instead of use month and year you can always truncate the date to first day of the month

```
 SELECT DATE_FORMAT(payment_date, '%Y-%m-01');
```

In that case join condition is easy save month like `yyyy-mm-01`

```
   ON a.month = DATE_FORMAT(payment_date, '%Y-%m-01')
```

Comment: its working like cream I just add COALESCE(SUM(o.order_total ),0) thanks

Comment: Yes forgot the `coalesce`