# Mysql group by month, return 0 if no data exists, with sum and where clause

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to aggregate data by month from two tables.  Often there is no record created for some months, I would like those months to be 0.  This is the basic query:

```
select tn.trans_date, SUM(COALESCE(stn.wit, tn.wit)) as Recreation
FROM fn_trans AS tn 
LEFT JOIN fn_sub_trans AS stn ON stn.L_trans_id = tn.trans_id 
WHERE (tn.L_cat_id IN (68,73) OR stn.L_cat_id in (68,73) ) AND tn.deleted_at IS NULL
group by YEAR(tn.trans_date), MONTH(tn.trans_date) 
ORDER BY tn.trans_date DESC LIMIT 24
```

This gives my a result like

```
2023-05-02  90.0000
2023-04-17  70.2600
2023-03-27  10.0000
2023-01-08  18.1700
```

But I want February there, but 0 instead of just missing.

I tried making a big table of years w/ months to act as an initial table.  Here is that query:

```
select tn.trans_date, SUM(COALESCE(stn.wit, tn.wit)) as Recreation, ym.year, ym.month
FROM yearmonth as ym
LEFT JOIN fn_trans AS tn ON (MONTH(tn.trans_date) = ym.month AND YEAR(tn.trans_date) = ym.year)
LEFT JOIN fn_sub_trans AS stn ON stn.L_trans_id = tn.trans_id 
WHERE (tn.L_cat_id IN (68,73) OR stn.L_cat_id in (68,73) ) AND tn.deleted_at IS NULL
group by YEAR(tn.trans_date), MONTH(tn.trans_date) 
ORDER BY tn.trans_date DESC LIMIT 24
```

But this doesn't work either, still no Feb.  I read around and I it seems it's because the WHERE clause makes my LEFT join not work like a typical LEFT join.

So somewhere suggested making it AND instead of WHERE.  Which I tried, and then I DO get February, but the math is all wrong.

```
2023-06-02  0.0000
2023-05-01  2813.9700
2023-04-06  17238.0400
2023-03-02  56157.4400
2023-02-01  6888.6900
2023-01-02  9867.5000
```

How do I get 0 values for missing (not null) records in a month.

I've tried looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75752/what-is-the-most-straightforward-way-to-pad-empty-dates-in-sql-results-on-eithe), but I'm trying to import this into grafana and can't use procedures or multiple queries.

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841549/mysql-select-the-count-of-records-for-every-month) which is where I learned about AND vs WHERE issue, which almost works, but then the math for the SUM/COALESCE doesn't work.